# Main Menu SubItem

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I try to create MainMenu at runtime , so I create two `Procedure` for that :

**Procedure 1:**

```
Procedure AddMenuItem ( Const Menu : TMenu ; Caption : String );
  Var MenuItem : TMenuItem;
Begin
  MenuItem := TMenuItem.Create(Menu);
  MenuItem.Caption := Caption;
  Menu.Items.Add(MenuItem);
End;
```

**Procedure 2:**

```
Procedure MenuAddSubItem ( Const Menu : TMenu ; Index : Integer ; Caption : String ) ;
  Var Item : TMenuItem;
Begin
  Item := TMenuItem.Create(Menu);
  Item.Caption := Caption;
  Menu.Items[Index].Add(Item);
End;
```

The first `Procedure` create `Items` , and the second one create `SubItems` .

The call of this two `Procedure` is :

```
AddMenuItem(MainMenu1,'File');
MenuAddSubItem(MainMenu1,0,'Open');
MenuAddSubItem(MainMenu1,0,'Save');
MenuAddSubItem(MainMenu1,0,'Save as..');
MenuAddSubItem(MainMenu1,0,'-');
MenuAddSubItem(MainMenu1,0,'Exit');
```

I want to add `Items` to **Save as..** `Item`, like :

File -> Save as.. -> PDF

File -> Save as.. -> Doc

File -> Save as.. -> Txt

So , my question is : How can I add `Items` to **Save as..** `Item` ?

**Update:** I try to create another `Procedure` to do that , So the `Procedure` 
search for **Save as..**  `Item` , When he find it , Add other items to it.

**Note:** I'm Using `Delphi 10 seattle`

Comment: Please leave comment after you downvote the Q , to know what's wrong and what is unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a `TMenuItem`, you can simply use its `Add` method to add other menu items to it.  Then, they are accessible through its `Items` property.

The code below shows how to do this and also how to do a recursive search through a menu to find a menu item with a specified caption and add a new menu item to its sub-menu.

```
function FindMenuItemByCaption(AMainMenu : TMainMenu; const Caption : String) : TMenuItem;


  function FindItemInner(Item : TMenuItem; const Caption : String) : TMenuItem;
  var
    i : Integer;
  begin
    Result := Nil;
    if Item.Caption = Caption then begin
      Result := Item;
      exit;
    end
    else begin
      for i := 0 to Item.Count - 1 do begin
        Result := FindItemInner(Item.Items[i], Caption);
        if Result <> Nil then
          Break;
      end;
    end;
  end;

begin
  Result := FindItemInner(AMainMenu.Items, Caption);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  FileItem,
  SaveItem,
  SaveAsItem,
  OtherItem,
  QuitItem : TMenuItem;
  i : integer;
  ItemToFind,
  ExtraItem : TMenuItem;
begin
  FileItem := TMenuItem.Create(Self);
  FileItem.Caption := 'File';
  MainMenu1.Items.Add(FileItem);

  SaveItem := TMenuItem.Create(Self);
  SaveItem.Caption := 'Save';
  FileItem.Add(SaveItem);

  SaveAsItem := TMenuItem.Create(Self);
  SaveAsItem.Caption := 'Save as';
  FileItem.Add(SaveAsItem);

  for i := 1 to 3 do begin
    OtherItem := TMenuItem.Create(Self);
    OtherItem.Caption := 'Other ' + IntToStr(i);
    SaveasItem.Add(OtherItem);
  end;

  QuitItem := TMenuItem.Create(Self);
  QuitItem.Caption := 'Quit';
  FileItem.Add(QuitItem);

  Caption := SaveAsItem.Items[2].Caption;

  ItemToFind := FindMenuItemByCaption(MainMenu1, 'Save as');
  Assert(ItemToFind <> Nil);
  ExtraItem := TMenuItem.Create(Self);
  ExtraItem.Caption := 'Extra';
  ItemToFind.Add(ExtraItem);
end;
```

You can, of course, populate `TPopUpMenu`s in a similar way;

Comment: Note: For what you use the variable **I** , the first one?                                      `function FindMenuItemByCaption(AMainMenu : TMainMenu; const Caption : String) : TMenuItem;
var
  i : Integer;    // For what ? remove it.

  function FindItemInner(Item : TMenuItem; const Caption : String) : TMenuItem;
  var
    i : Integer;`

Comment: @MartynA w.r.t. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41700180/976391 - it did added though - a code example, if incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

> So the Procedure search for Save as.. Item , When he find it , Add other items to it.

That is a rather strange idea. Why should you search for the item you already know? Or put it another way - why would you forget the item that you still have to use ?

Searching again by caption is both redundant, slower and error-prone (typos or localization).

Just keep the value while you need it and only forget it after you would no more search for it.

```
function MenuAddSubItem ( Const Menu : TMenuItem ; Const Caption : String ): TMenuItem; overload;
  Var Item : TMenuItem;
Begin
  Item := TMenuItem.Create(Menu);
  Item.Caption := Caption;
  Menu.Add(Item);
  Result := Item;
End;

function MenuAddSubItem ( Const Menu : TMenu ; Const Index : Integer ; Const Caption : String ): TMenuItem; overload;
Begin
  Result := MenuAddSubItem( Menu.Items[Index], Caption );
End;


var miSaveAs: TMenuItem;

AddMenuItem(MainMenu1,'File');
MenuAddSubItem(MainMenu1,0,'Open');
MenuAddSubItem(MainMenu1,0,'Save');
miSaveAs := MenuAddSubItem(MainMenu1,0,'Save as..');
MenuAddSubItem(MainMenu1,0,'-');
MenuAddSubItem(MainMenu1,0,'Exit');

MenuAddSubItem(miSaveAs,'in PDF format');
MenuAddSubItem(miSaveAs,'in MS Word format');
MenuAddSubItem(miSaveAs,'in Plain Text format');
```

PS. you procedures also lack setting `Hint` and `OnClick` properties....